# Como fazer o Google entender meus Links?

Tags: seo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se digitarmos Globo no Google o resultado aparece conforme a imagem acima.

1 - Como posso fazer com que meu site fique assim também ?

2 - O Google faz isso sozinho ?

Estou na ferramenta do Google WebMaster Tools e quando eu faço um teste aparece o seguinte para mim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fala que o caminho do meu site é inacessível.
Mas o endereço funciona normalmente no navegador e tem a `meta tag`:

`<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">`

Ou seja, é para fazer a indexação.

---

Entrei agora no site do Google que testa Dados Estruturados. Quando vou testar aparece:

> O URL está inacessível. Verifique se é possível acessar o robots.txt e se o servidor está respondendo com um código de status 200.

Eu entrei no site e verifiquei que está respondendo com código 200. Andei pesquisando e diz que pode ser alguma coisa em minhas `meta tags`.

Elas estão assim:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ strip_tags(trans('quem-somos.principal.chamada')) }}">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
<meta itemprop="url" content="http://dominio.com.br/>

<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt-br" href="{{ URLController::format(null,Request::url()) }}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="{{ URLController::format('en',Request::url()) }}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="{{ URLController::format('es',Request::url()) }}" />
```

Comment: Com diz aquela propaganda de cerveja: "Boa pergunta" +1

Comment: Pergunta também como se faz para ficar com a barra de pesquisa!

Comment: Não entendi @WallaceMaxters. Barra de pesquisa ? Você fala o Google Instant ?

Comment: Na imagem da sua pergunta tem uma barra de pesquisa em cima dos links. "Resultados de globo.com". Quero colocar isso no [cardvantagens](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=cardvantagens&oq=cardvantagens&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.1936j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), a rede social aqui da empresa também.

Comment: Quando tive que fazer isso usei a ferramenta do Google WebMasters, bem simples.

Comment: @DeeSouza me deu inspiração para perguntar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93422/o-que-influencia-no-tempo-de-indexa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-google

Comment: Ah entendi @WallaceMaxters. Nem tinha reparado nessa barra. Nunca reparei. Muito boa ideia.

Comment: Agora que o @bigown já respondeu, você vai ter que fazer outra pergunta :ṕ

Comment: https://cse.google.com.br/cse/create/new É aqui.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters na verdade tem que aplicar isso aqui para a barra de pesquisa dentro do resultado. https://schema.org/WebSite

Comment: Já venho estudando esse cara a um tempo @DeeSouza

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Eu implementei ela nesse site que estava me ocasionando esse problema. Se funcionar eu te falo.

Comment: @DeeSouza, percebi que a Globo usa o `input[type=search]`. Será que isso pode influenciar?

Comment: Eu acho que não. Acredito que seja só para diferenciar o `text` do `search`, assim como o `date`. O `date` até que é necessário, mas o `search` não li nenhuma vantagem ainda.

Comment: Falo por questão de semântica, onde os robots vão ler, e não que `search` de uma nova funcionalidade.

Comment: O SiteLinks deu certo! Em apenas 3 dias... isso mostra que minhas técnicas de SEO estão boas. Agora só falta o campo de busca aparecer entre o Site e os SiteLinks. Vamos ver...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isto chama-se *sitelinks*. Não é garantido que ele apareça. O critério é do mecanismo de busca. Você pode dar condições melhores para que isto aconteça, mas são raros os sites que conseguem. As visitas ao site influenciam.

Leia a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) com mais detalhes do que fazer para dar as condições mínimas para aparecer para seu site.

Um dos mecanismos para facilitar que ele ative é ter um *sitemap*. É um [formato](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) desenvolvido para ajudar os mecanismos de busca darem mais semântica ao seu site. Hoje existem outros mecanismos que reconhecem isto.

Um bom começo de como usá-lo pode ser obtido no [*help center*](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=pt) da Google. A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) tem bastante informação útil sobre o formato.

Existem ferramentas que ajudam montá-lo. Evidentemente é só uma ajuda. Se pudesse fazer tudo bom automaticamente, não precisaria dele.

Ele é muito útil quando o site é complexo e possuem tecnologias que dificultam rastreá-lo. Como por exemplo JavaScript. Hoje há um mito que o Google entende páginas com JS. Entende certas coisas, ele não pode interpretar tudo o que um usuário faria na página. Então se você tem um SPA um *sitemap* pode ajudar muito, mas duvido que seja viável fazer um para este tipo de página, as combinações são muitas.

Obviamente o site precisa estar apropriadamente indexado para isso ocorrer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Os mecanismos não garantem que isto será feito. Eles podem usar como quiserem. Cada mecanismo tem um critério para identificar como usar. Fora isto pode ter algum problema que está impedindo o seu uso. Não que seja um erro, mas alguma situação que determina que não precisa fazer isto. Não como está cada um, mas costuma demorar um pouco para fazer análise.

Comment: Ainda assim, nada garante que o *sitemap* será usado. Se eu ver alguma coisa específica, eu falo.

Comment: Não estar sendo indexado é outro problema. Claro que ele ser indexado é condição primordial, mas não basta isto.

Comment: Sim, mas esses problemas tem a ver com a indexação apenas.