# o que influencia no tempo de indexação do Google?

Tags: seo

Quando eu tinha um blog no *Blogger* (Blogspot), eu notava que demorava de 1 a 3 dias para que o conteúdo fosse indexado pelo Google.

Porém, esses dias atrás, fiz uma pergunta aqui no *Stackoverflow* que, com menos de 1 minuto, apareceu no Google.

Quais são os fatores que implicam no tempo em que o Google demora para indexar um determinado conteúdo de um site?

Essa pergunta foi inspirada por essa outra [Como fazer o Google entender meus Links?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93419/como-fazer-o-google-entender-meus-links?noredirect=1#comment189294_93419)

Answer (score 3):

Uma das principais coisas que influenciam essa indexação é o que o pessoal chama de semântica web. Em resumo é o ato de você fornecer ao indexador padrões que demonstrem o que você está informando em cada elemento HTML.

http://www.w3c.br/Padroes/WebSemantica

Para tal foi desenvolvido em HTML 5 o que chamamos de microdata. Em resumo são tags que auxiliam na identificação de padrões e tipos. Veja:

http://www.w3c.br/cursos/html5/conteudo/capitulo20.html

Esse é um fator importante para a indexação ser mais performática além de tornar a busca do usuário mais acertiva. Aliada a isso ainda temos o volume de acesso ao determinado site. Esse volume demonstra o quão relevante é o site para o network, logo, quanto mais relevante, mais cedo o site será indexado.